# ROS, MIPS Linux, Open Wrt and Arduino

Tags: arduino, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

My name is Micheal, I'm from Middle Volga Center of Robotics (the Lenin's motherland, Ulyanovsk, Russia). We're making some robots for our projects, and I want to tell some features of work of our robots. Next, we can present our work in all views.

Most of supporting robots not available in Russia.

So.. Now we still making robots based on Arduino-like device connection with wi-fi routerD-Link DIR-320 (200 mhz processor, 32 mb ram) where installed OpenWrt firmware. Arduino connecting on UART interface with DIR-320 and manipulating drivers and sensors. Why we chose this hardware? Mostly, we can receive it from Russia. Hardware from another internet-shops located abroad going to us about 3-5 weeks.

So... I have some questions and looking for advices :)

Can I built ROS for OpenWrt or other MIPS Linux? I haven't found some packages for this.
Can I take part in developming ROS? I can make soem code for MIPS, Arduino and many drivers&sensors. Also I'm interesting in Artificial Intelligence. I'm registered at code.ros.org and want to find  next actions for work. Now my robots can be controlled and manipulated by xmpp and I want to go next.

If MIPS and Open Wrt not supported, I would like to be maintainer for this. I work with Linux mor then 6 years.

Thank you! My email is dronov.m.m@gmail.com

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10928/ros,-mips-linux,-open-wrt-and-arduino/) by [Mechanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/955/mechanic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A google search suggests that there are others working with similar devices:

- [ROS, meet Arduino](http://www.ros.org/news/2011/02/ros-meet-arduino.html)
- [OpenWRT toolchain message](http://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20110714.033808.4487ab0d.attach)

You might have better luck contacting people using similar tools on the `ros-users` mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0